# MySQL query working in phpmyadmin but not in php code any reason why?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I am using the following query and would like the results from the query to appear within single quotes such as '10AM'.

```html
$sql2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT concat('''', appointment_time ,''''), concat('''', appointment_end_time ,'''') FROM Appointments WHERE appointment_with LIKE 'Sarah'");

if (!$sql2) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysqli_error());
}

while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql2)) {

    $time = array($row2['appointment_time']. "," ." " . $row2['appointment_end_time']);

    $appointment = [];

    foreach ($time as $appointment){
        echo $appointment;
    }
```

This works fine when I run the code in phpmyadmin but not within my php code as I get the following message.

> Notice: Undefined index: appointment_time in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/booking-system/index.php on line 140
>
> Notice: Undefined index: appointment_end_time in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/booking-system/index.php on line 140
>   ,

Why is this happening?

Comment: Do a `print_r($row2)` and see for yourself

Comment: `SELECT concat('''', appointment_time ,'''') as appointment_time,......`

Comment: completely forgot about print_r

Comment: `var_dump($row2);` It appears you are producing unnamed columns (without aliases) surrounded by quotes. The actual array keys are probably literally `CONCAT(....)`.  Why do you feel you need the `CONCAT()`?

Comment: If you are trying to produce quoted results, I would very much recommend handling the presentation (the quoting) in PHP code in your output loop rather than doing it in the SQL.

Comment: Do those concat's actually work i.e. `''''` ???

Comment: And what function do they perform?

Comment: This line `$appointment = [];` does not need to be there either

Comment: @RiggsFolly, I was just updating the answer as that whole loop looks mostly redundant.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give your fields an alias in your SQL...

```
$sql2 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT concat('''', appointment_time ,'''') as appointment_time, 
            concat('''', appointment_end_time ,'''') as appointment_end_time 
        FROM Appointments 
        WHERE appointment_with LIKE 'Sarah'");
```

As for the main loop, you seem to build an array to print it out again, you could reduce that code to...

```
while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql2)) {
    echo $row2['appointment_time']. ", " . 
               $row2['appointment_end_time'];
}
```